# Overlay div over another div

Tags: css, html, overlay

I've tried suggestions found here (either using negative margin-bottom or using position: aboslute) for overlaying a div over another div, and it has worked fine in other cases. But for some reasons it won't work now.

Here's my html:

```
       <div id="header" class="lightgradient">

            <div id="headerContent" class="container">

                <div id="logo" class="span-6">

                    <a href="/">

                        <img src="/images/logo.png" width="230" height="62" />

                    </a>

                </div>

                <div id="menucontainer" class="span-14"><ul id="menu"><li>

<a href='/Services/Index'>TJ&#196;NSTER</a></li>

<li>

<a href='/About/References'>KUNDER</a></li>

<li>

<a href='/About'>OM OSS</a></li>

<li>

<a href='/About/Contact'>KONTAKT</a></li>

</ul></div>

                <div id="logindisplay" class="span-2">

                        <a href="/Account/LogOn">Logga in</a>



                </div>

            </div>

        </div>



    <div class="banner">

        <div class="container white">

            <div class="span-12">
[etc...]
```

I want the logo to jut down over the "banner".

I tried this e.g.:

```
#logo
{
    float: left;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
    z-index: 40;
}
```

But that won't work. It moves the div and logo image fine, but the image is hidden at the bottom by the banner, even though I set a high z-index, and also I get a scrollbar inside the div that holds the logo...

How do I make the image lay on top of the banner, and how do I get rid of the scrollbar?

EDIT:

Here's the banner css too:

```
.banner
{
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#70b8ea', endColorstr='#2c6dc3'); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#70b8ea), to(#2c6dc3)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #70b8ea,  #2c6dc3);
    border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup won't allow the `margin-bottom` trick to work since your `#logo` div is nested in a different set of elements.

You'll have to position the logo absolutely and place it relative to a parent element that wraps both the `#logo` div and the `.banner` div.

http://jsfiddle.net/DOSBeats/NXgq6/

Here is an example using `position:absolute`. In the example I didn't use `position:relative` on a parent element, but if you are using a grid system I would check to make sure the main `.row` or `.container-(12||16)` has the `position:relative` property set.

This will ensure any `left:15px; top:25px;` will be centered with the rest of the content.

EDIT:

After reviewing your code here is how you need to update your CSS/HTML.

1. Remove all references to `position:relative` from `#header` and `#headerContent`
2. After your `#wrap` div you'll need to add another `<div class="container">` and close it off just before the `</div>` that closes the `#wrap` element.
3. Change `overflow:auto` to `overflow:hidden` on your `#headerContent` element to get rid of the scroll bars to the far right.

Comment: Thank you very much for the illustrative example! However, I still can't get it to work, using absolute positioning either. I am trying to use a framework (but starting to regret it), Blueprint. But each ancestor div does have position:relative set, which they should if I understand you correctly? I also have a "wrap" div (with position:relative) that wraps both the logo and the banner, but it is not an immediate parent of either. But as far as I can see from your example they don't have a common immediate parent their either, right? How come your example works, but my stuff doesn't...?

Comment: An absolutely positioned element will get it's starting point from the closets parent element who's position is set to relative. I would only have the main parent element set to relative. Can you post a link somewhere so I can check it out? I'll be able to better give you direction if I can see live code. A quick way to understand it is by saying "I am absolutely positioning x element relative to y element"

Comment: Sure here's the address: www.testserver.dita.nu/Home/Test. Only that page is relevant, the other ones on the site haven't been rewritten to fit blueprint yet.

Comment: I updated my above post to help you achieve your goal. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: Well, it did accomplish getting the logo outside and above, and it got rid of the scroll bars, but there's a problem: because I removed position:relative on the headerContent, the logo doesn't seem to be absolutely positioned relative to the headerContent anymore, which means it is placed outside it (to the left), and out of its flow. And this means the entire menu is shifted left (to the place where the logo should be)...

Comment: You could either put a `margin-left` on the menu or `position:absolute` to make up for the difference.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I could do that. Thanks for all your help!